# What captured this Pokemon?

Tags: detective-pikachu

In Pokémon Detective Pikachu, Mewtwo is captured by 4 floating electric balls. Are these a specific Pokémon (Magnemite-related, perhaps)? Or are these just high-tech machines?

I watched the film and they seemed like machines, but a friend argued they were Magnezones. Who is correct?

Comment: In the second Pokemon movie, "The power of One" (2000), the main antagonist uses similar floating electric machines to capture Moltres, Zapdos, Articuno and Lugia. In the animated series, there is a character called "Pokemon Hunter J" who also uses several high-tech non-Pokeball devices to capture Pokemon. And of course Team Rocket uses tons of original devices to capture Pikachu (nets, magnets, giant pincers, cages, vacuum machines, etc). So these floating balls from Pokemon Detective Pikachu are not entirely a first for the Pokemon universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Detective_Pikachu_(movie)), you are correct. The only evolutionary form in Detective Pikachu was Magnemite. Considering how incredibly literal the interpretations of the Pokemon were in the movie, the things that captured MewTwo were not Magnemites.